# R: Defining a function (and/or using apply() or for loop) to perform a set of procedures repeatedly

Tags: r

R: Defining a function (and/or using apply() or for loop) to perform a set of procedures repeatedly

Language: R
OS: Windows 7

I would like to know how to create a function and/or construct apply() or for() loop statement(s) that will allow me to accomplish the task described below.

I am working in R on a Windows 7 machine. sessionInfo() is pasted below my question.

I have two dataframes, SUBJ and ANNO. I would like to create a new dataframe (Output) from performing an operation on a subset of columns in SUBJ, with that column subset being defined by the results of an operation on ANNO.

Below, I first create the two fake dataframes, SUBJ and ANNO. Next, I create the empty Output dataframe, with rownames and colnames taken from
SUBJ and ANNO, respectively.

Then, I perform the desired operation for the first column of ANNO. That is: 
1) I process the first column of ANNO, ANNO1, identifying the set of row.names corresponding to rows where ANNO1==1 and saving that set to a character vector, ROWSlookup.
2) Then, for each row in SUBJ, I calculate the sum of values for the subset of columns that appear in the ROWSlookup list and put the resulting
sum in the ANNO1 column of the Ouptut dataframe.

The actual datasets (represented by SUBJ and ANNO) are very large. So I would like to create a function and/or construct apply() or for() loop statement(s), that will enable me to efficiently complete the desired Output dataframe. That is, I want the function to create a ROWSlookup for each column of ANNO, calculate a sum of the values in the corresponding columns of SUBJ and enter that sum into the corresponding cell of Output.

```
# CREATE FAKE SUBJ
    SUBJ <-    matrix(c(0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0), 10, 10)`
    rownames(SUBJ) <- c("subj1", "subj2", "subj3", "subj4", "subj5", "subj6", "subj7", "subj8", "subj9", "subj10")
    colnames(SUBJ) <- c("rs1", "rs2", "rs3", "rs4", "rs5", "rs6", "rs7", "rs8", "rs9", "rs10") 
    SUBJ<- as.data.frame(SUBJ)
SUBJ

           #rs1 rs2 rs3 rs4 rs5 rs6 rs7 rs8 rs9 rs10
    #subj1    0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0    1
    #subj2    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1    0
    #subj3    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0    0
    #subj4    1   1   2   1   1   0   1   0   0    1
    #subj5    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0    0
    #subj6    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
    #subj7    2   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0    0
    #subj8    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0    2
    #subj9    1   0   0   0   1   2   0   0   2    0
    #subj10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0

# CREATE FAKE ANNO
    ANNO <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0), 
        8, 8)
    length(c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0))
    rownames(ANNO) <- c("rs1", "rs2", "rs3", "rs4", "rs5", "rs6", "rs7", "rs8")
    colnames(ANNO) <- c("ANNO1","ANNO2","ANNO3","ANNO4","ANNO5","ANNO6","ANNO7","ANNO8") 
    ANNO<- as.data.frame(ANNO)

ANNO

        #ANNO1 ANNO2 ANNO3 ANNO4 ANNO5 ANNO6 ANNO7 ANNO8
    #rs1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
    #rs2     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0
    #rs3     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     1
    #rs4     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     0
    #rs5     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
    #rs6     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
    #rs7     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
    #rs8     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

# CREATE EMPTY OUTPUT DATAFRAME TO HOLD THE (EVENTUAL) PROCESSED VALUES
    Output<-data.frame(matrix(nrow=nrow(SUBJ), ncol=ncol(ANNO)))

# SET ROWNAMES AND COLNAMES OF OUTPUT DF
    row.names(Output)<- row.names(SUBJ)
    colnames(Output)<- colnames(ANNO)
    Output
           #ANNO1 ANNO2 ANNO3 ANNO4 ANNO5 ANNO6 ANNO7 ANNO8
    #subj1     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    #subj2     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    #subj3     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    #subj4     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    #subj5     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    #subj6     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    #subj7     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    #subj8     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    #subj9     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    #subj10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA

# PROCESS FIRST COLUMN OF ANNO, ANNO1, IDENTIFYING THE row.names corresponding to rows where ANNO1==1
# SAVE THOSE row.names TO A VECTOR TO SERVE AS LOOKUP VALUES

    ROWSlookup <- row.names(ANNO[which(ANNO$ANNO1==1),])

#[1] "rs4" "rs5"

# FOR EACH ROW IN SUBJ, CALCULATE THE SUM OF VALUES WITHIN THE COLs IN ROWSlookup LIST AND PUT THE RESULTING VALUES
# IN THE ANNO1 COL OF THE OUTPUT DF (Count_TEST)

    Output$ANNO1 <- apply(SUBJ[,which(names(SUBJ) %in% ROWSlookup)],1,sum,na.rm=TRUE)
    Output
           #ANNO1 ANNO2 ANNO3 ANNO4 ANNO5 ANNO6 ANNO7 ANNO8
    #subj1      1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    #subj2      0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    #subj3      0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    #subj4      2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    #subj5      0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    #subj6      0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    #subj7      1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    #subj8      0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    #subj9      1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    #subj10     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA



sessionInfo()

#R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
#Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#
#locale:
#[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
#[5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    
#
#attached base packages:
 #[1] stats4    parallel  splines   grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#
#other attached packages:
 #[1] QuantPsyc_1.5         boot_1.3-13           perturb_2.05          RCurl_1.95-4.5        bitops_1.0-6          car_2.0-22           
 #[7] reprtree_0.6          plotrix_3.5-10        rpart.plot_1.4-5      sqldf_0.4-7.1         RSQLite.extfuns_0.0.1 RSQLite_1.0.0        
#[13] gsubfn_0.6-6          proto_0.3-10          XML_3.98-1.1          RMySQL_0.9-3          DBI_0.3.1             mlbench_2.1-1        
#[19] polycor_0.7-8         sfsmisc_1.0-26        quantregForest_0.2-3  tree_1.0-35           maptree_1.4-7         cluster_1.15.3       
#[25] mice_2.22             VIM_4.0.0             colorspace_1.2-4      randomForest_4.6-10   ROCR_1.0-5            gplots_2.15.0        
#[31] caret_6.0-37          partykit_0.8-0        biomaRt_2.18.0        NCBI2R_1.4.6          snpStats_1.12.0       betareg_3.0-5        
#[37] arm_1.7-07            lme4_1.1-7            Rcpp_0.11.3           Matrix_1.1-4          nlme_3.1-118          mvtnorm_1.0-1        
#[43] taRifx_1.0.6          sos_1.3-8             brew_1.0-6            R.utils_1.34.0        R.oo_1.18.0           R.methodsS3_1.6.1    
#[49] rattle_3.3.0          jsonlite_0.9.13       httpuv_1.3.2          httr_0.5              gmodels_2.15.4.1      ggplot2_1.0.0        
#[55] JGR_1.7-16            iplots_1.1-7          JavaGD_0.6-1          party_1.0-18          modeltools_0.2-21     strucchange_1.5-0    
#[61] sandwich_2.3-2        zoo_1.7-11            pROC_1.7.3            e1071_1.6-4           psych_1.4.8.11        gtools_3.4.1         
#[67] functional_0.6        modeest_2.1           stringi_0.3-1         languageR_1.4.1       utility_1.3           data.table_1.9.4     
#[73] xlsx_0.5.7            xlsxjars_0.6.1        rJava_0.9-6           snow_0.3-13           doParallel_1.0.8      iterators_1.0.7      
#[79] foreach_1.4.2         reshape2_1.4          reshape_0.8.5         plyr_1.8.1            xtable_1.7-4          stringr_0.6.2        
#[85] foreign_0.8-61        Hmisc_3.14-6          Formula_1.1-2         survival_2.37-7       class_7.3-11          MASS_7.3-35          
#[91] nnet_7.3-8            Revobase_7.2.0        RevoMods_7.2.0        RevoScaleR_7.2.0      lattice_0.20-27       rpart_4.1-5          
#
#loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 #[1] abind_1.4-0         acepack_1.3-3.3     BiocGenerics_0.8.0  BradleyTerry2_1.0-5 brglm_0.5-9         caTools_1.17.1      chron_2.3-45       
 #[8] coda_0.16-1         codetools_0.2-9     coin_1.0-24         DEoptimR_1.0-2      digest_0.6.4        flexmix_2.3-12      gdata_2.13.3       
#[15] glmnet_1.9-8        gtable_0.1.2        KernSmooth_2.23-13  latticeExtra_0.6-26 lmtest_0.9-33       minqa_1.2.4         munsell_0.4.2      
#[22] nloptr_1.0.4        pkgXMLBuilder_1.0   png_0.1-7           RColorBrewer_1.0-5  revoIpe_1.0         robustbase_0.92-2   scales_0.2.4       
#[29] sp_1.0-16           tcltk_3.0.3         tools_3.0.3         vcd_1.3-2
```

Comment: Your operations will probably be much faster if you keep these as matrices rather than converting them to data.frames

Comment: Thanks, Gregor. Unfortunately, the actual datasets I'm working with are dataframes, so I wanted the fake data to mimic those.

Comment: Well, in that case good job making a nice minimal example that is still reflective of the true problem. Many posters take more than a few questions to learn to do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we can first create a row/col numeric index from the comparison `ANNO==1` using `which` with argument `arr.ind=TRUE`.  The `indx` also have `rownames` same as the `ANNO` dataset.  `Split` the rownames of the `indx` with the `second` column of `indx` (`column` index) to get a list of rownames.  This rownames can be used as column index of `SUBJ` (same column names) to subset.  For example when you do `SUBJ[c('rs1','rs2')]`, the result will be a subset with only that columns of `SUBJ`.  Similarly, the `SUBJ[x]` (where `x` reflects the split rownames) will subset the `SUBJ` as these are also the column names of `SUBJ`.  Then, use `rowSums` on the subset dataset.

```
indx <- which(ANNO==1,arr.ind=TRUE)
Output[] <- lapply(split(row.names(indx), indx[,2]), 
               function(x) rowSums(SUBJ[x], na.rm=TRUE))
```

Or instead of usign `lapply`, we can also use `Map`.  The idea is similar.  Each `list` element of `y` will be `split` rownames and `x` will be the the whole `SUBJ` dataset.

```
Output[] <- Map(function(x,y) rowSums(x[y], na.rm=TRUE), 
                 list(SUBJ),split(row.names(indx), indx[,2]))
```

A `data.frame` is also a `list` but with same length of its elements.  So, by using `Output[]` (which has the same `dim` of `SUBJ`), the result will be a `data.frame` while keeping the structure intact of `Output`.

Comment: Thank you, akrun. Both work perfectly. I would love to understand the scripts a bit better if you have time to explain. I think I understand the first two lines of the first option, but am unclear how R 'knows' that SUBJ[x] refers to the specified row subset defined in line 2. Also, how does Output[] <- allow the new variable values to be assigned to the correct row and column in Output? Thanks again!

Comment: @KDA Added some explanation.  BTW, you don't need to create an `Output` dataset.  You can do `do.call(cbind, lapply(split(row.names(indx), ...`